# group List[(List[Char, Int], String)] into List[(List[(Char, Int)], List[String])]

Tags: scala

I have a `List[(List[(Char,Int)],String)]` like this

```
val words = List((List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1)),"ate"),
                 (List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1)),"eat"),
                 (List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1)),"tea"))
```

which represent the occurrences of each char in each word.

Now I want to group this list by occurrences to produce a list with one item like this

```
val grouped = List((List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1)),(List("ate","eat","tea"))))
```

I tried `words groupBy(i => i._1)` but its output was

```
(List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)),List((List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)),ate), (List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)),eat), (List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)),tea)))
```

**Note**: I want use neither `for expression` nor `for loop`, I like using higher-order function like `map` and `flatMap`.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Are you sure you want `List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1))` in grouped (I mean, not a sum of occurences)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes I am sure, I need the output exactly as `val grouped`. as you see all words have the same occurances

Comment: @MatthewFarwell yes, but I tried many times to get it in scala style but failed, loser :')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toList.sorted).toList
```

Comment: +1. You may want to do a sort before the call to groupBy so that List(('a',1),('e',1),('t',1)) and List(('e',1),('a',1),('t',1)) don't end up as separate entries (or better: change it to a set).